# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

Our current chatroom name is "The Drug Store." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- "The Nineteenth Byte" for Code Golf
- "The Junk Drawer" for Lifehacks
- "The Percolator" for Coffee
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

Stolen from the [Coffee Meta](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom/), which was stolen from [Lifehacks meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom), which was in turn stolen from [PPCG meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/lets-think-of-a-creative-name-for-our-chatroom). Thanks to Doorknob for writing all of the previous ones. :P

Comment: Let's remind the subtitle of our Area51 proposition: "Beta Q&A site for medical specialists, students, dietitians and anyone with health-related questions". I'd like not to focus on a too specific wording, but find something that anyone can relate to.

Comment: "The Drug Store" is [my name](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22477?m=20845999#20845999). :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## The waiting room

Everyone has been in one of these. They are a place to talk sometimes.

Cons: it's generally not a happy place for everyone. The term "waiting" feels negative.

Comment: Why does this have 7 upvotes, yet the accepted answer only has 6 upvotes?

Comment: @Mew maybe the time when he accepted the answer, things were different.

Comment: @Mew I accepted it before when "The Pharmacy" has more votes than "The Waiting Room". I've fixed it now.

Comment: 1+ but this is not always for just medical places, but anywhere really. Still, I think the meaning is implied. :)

Comment: `The term "waiting" feels negative` -> Pro

Comment: The waiting room is already and will be boring, people want fast answers ryt? So, what about something like "No waiting room"

Comment: *The term "waiting" feels negative* well not for me. I'm afraid of doctors (despite them proving me wrong most of the time) so for me the *negative* part starts when *the waiting* ends.

Answer (score 7):

## The Pharmacy

A replacement for drug store. The term seems more international and less pejorative as "drugs" are in many countries deemed harmful.

Answer (score 1):

## The Drugstore

Vote for this if you wish to keep the current chatroom name

Comment: +1, but i think it would look better without a space.

Comment: I'd prefer "Pharmacy" as it might seem less pejorative and more international.

Comment: @M'vy If you post it as an option, I'd definitely vote for "The Pharmacy".

Comment: @Nate so be it.

Comment: @Scimonster Yeah it does look better

Answer (score 1):

## Ambulance Radio

Radio, live transmission ♪

Comment: "Let's connect to the radio and have a chat". I like it ! :)

Comment: Glad you liked it. *"The Waiting Room"* is an OK name and I guess I'm a bit late to make this proposal. *"Ambulance Radio"* seems to have a bit more personality in my humble opinion and it sets a different tone. Thank you for your vote :)

Answer (score 1):

## The Triage Station

It might not have the same chatty feel as **The Waiting Room**, but the link to the field of medicine is more apparent and, and I think the name fits given that much of what happens in site specific chat rooms is discussion about how serious various issues are and how to handle individual cases (i.e. Does this answer make any sense? Should this issue be brought up on meta? Does anybody know of better references for this topic? Etc.).

Answer (score -1):

**The Healing Room**

*Note: its never to late*

Answer (score -3):

## Intensive Care Unit

---

Answer (score -4):

## Eliza

Ok, this is a physical health site. But the name deserves a chance.

[who is eliza?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)

Answer (score -4):

## The Healing Pool

A laid back place where people congregate, centered around the betterment of their health.

Answer (score -4):

**The Best Medicine**
As in "Laughter is the best medicine".
Only appropriate if we're being funny, though.

Answer (score -5):

## The Immune System

Not sure if that's too cheesy/obvious.

Comment: why not the Digestive system?

Answer (score -5):

**The kilter[*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=kilter&oq=kilter&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) Room**

Answer (score -6):

### The Surgery

---

In the UK (at least), doctors' normal places of workare called surgeries.  And in other places, well, they're places where medical procedures are done.

Answer (score -10):

### Not A&E

Just to let people know at start what the chat isn't about.

Answer (score -16):

### Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

It was first added to the Oxford English Dictionary in 1986, later popularized by Disney musical film. It basically means: extraordinarily good and wonderful.